# Is it possible in Java to hide classes from java.lang with custom classes?

Tags: java

Is it possible in Java to hide classes from the platform with custom classes? For instance to create a custom java.lang.String or custom java.lang.StringBuffer? I am asking because I recently discovered there is an option in C# /nostdlib that allows you to redefine the entire System namespace and I was wondering if Java had something similar.

Note, C#'s /nostdlib is a compiler option, not something that gets taken into account at runtime.

Comment: It is always possible to hide classes. Just define the class in your code. Then any reference to such class actually refers to the code defined provided the class you wrote is visible from the current scope

Comment: @Algorithms it's a lot more complicated if you want to redfine parts of the standard library as the OP seems to desire.

Comment: @Algorithms I don't think that's the way it works, the bootstrap class loader already loaded these classes from the platform. Even with a custom class loader, the recommended contract is to delegate to the parent class loader and these would always be found. I think to do this you have to modify the bootstrap loader functioning.

Comment: You don't have to modify the bootstrap loader, you just have to tell it to look in a different place on startup. Or change the files in the place it normally looks, but that's more dangerous.

Comment: @Antimony yes, erm I said "modify the bootstrap loader functioning" the word "functioning" was on the next line. From your replies I am getting that it is possible to do this but it is a runtime concern, not something you can indicate to the compiler? Not something you as a developer could enforce?

Comment: The compiler simply creates classfiles. First off it's impossible since the JVM has obviously already done the startup stuff before even looking at your code. Second off, it'd be extremely dangerous to let random developers change the functioning of the JVM itself. Now assuming you're running with full permissions, you can always hack something up, for example restarting the JVM with new options. But these options are all ugly, nonportable, and may get your sued by Oracle.

Comment: Think about it this way - even a binary can't really enforce which DLLs it gets linked against, and trying to modify system libraries at runtime is likely to get you rightfully pilloried.

Comment: I think the question needs some help. It's obviously possible, but "yes, it's possible" doesn't seem to answer what you really want to know. Can you add some detail?

Comment: @Ickster Ok, I think people got confused if the option was a compiler option or a VM option? I tried to make that clearer now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your own classes for the library classes. When starting you can define a `-bootclasspath` to define your own class library.

This will not an easy task because some classes are tighgtly bound to the VM running, e.g. the class `String`. You have to look at the JLS for such cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the standard library or substitute your own for personal use, but Oracle doesn't support this and doesn't allow you to distribute the modified version to others. There are various commandline and configuration option to tell the JVM where to look for classes. Replacing bootstrap classes is harder but it is possible.

Note that creating your own version entirely from scratch will be difficult because several classes (`Object` and `Class` at the very least) are necessarily tied very strongly to the JVM implementation. You'll probably want to keep all the classes that use native code the same for simplicity.

Note that this is different from class Shadowing, which is a purely compile time concept that occurs when multiple identifiers conflict, usually due to imports (`java.lang.*` is implicitly imported and there's nothing you can do about that). These conflicts are generally resolved by either silently using one of the possibilities or raising a compile error depending on the situation (see the JLS for details).

Comment: Ok, so the answer seems to be no there really is no equivalent in Java to C#'s /nostdlib compiler flag..

Comment: @Mish Unfortunately I'm not familiar with C# so I can't tell you what the Java equivalent is. It looks like the closest equivalent is `-bootclasspath` though. Maybe it would help if you said why you were trying to do this.

Answer (score 1):

In order to replace a java.lang class, or some other "system" class you must modify the boot classpath.  If you run Java from a command line this is easily accomplished, but if you run it in some sort of "environment" you may not be allowed to make that change.

Additionally, many java.lang et al classes have native method implementations, and you must either supply your own replacement or somehow arrange to reuse the existing implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Sun/Oracle does not allow that by the license of the JSE/JDK.
However, I recently learned, that [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/) can do amazing things, like adding methods or overwriting methods of the java.lang.* package.

Groovy is based on Java/JVM, so you can easily combine them within one application.